# How do I import a chrome devtools coverage to analyze it?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, code-coverage, chromium

Chrome/Chromium has this amazing coverage report feature (DevTools > Coverage Tab). Chrome allows to me export this report as JSON. But I cant find a way to import this report to Chrome again.

How do I import the JSON export created by the Coverage Tab?

My Chrome Version is 105.0.5195.127

Background: I want to analyze a coverage report created by Puppeteer (which is in fact Chrome).

I am also happy if you point me to a tool that visualizes coverage from these JSON files.

Comment: I have come up with puppeteer to Istanbul, but it does not support sourcemaps.